Raw, aged advocaat?
I've been thinking about making the Dutch egg liqueur advocaat recently and found that my usual source (Classic Liqueurs by Long & Kibbey, which I've had luck with in the past) differed notably from other recipes on two counts. First, the advocaat is not cooked--everything is blended together for 30 seconds. I'm not worried about raw eggs in this case but other recipes seem to be prepared more like a custard. Second, the advocaat is aged for 1-2 weeks in the fridge after bottling; this is consistent with other liqueurs I've made, but I can't find any other advocaat recipes that do the same thing. Is this an accepted variation or is it completely anomalous?
Recipe:
1 1/4 cups granulated sugar
3/4 tsp. vanilla
1/2 tsp lemon extract
1 cup vodka
5 whole eggs
1 egg yolk
2/3 cup evaporated milk

Put ingredients in blender, blend for 30 seconds or until mixed well. Pour into container, cap, and refrigerate. Age for 1 to 2 weeks to mellow. Color will intensify as it ages, reaching a more traditional light shade of yellow.
Variation: Substitute 1/4 to 1/2 cup brandy for same volume of vodka.
